# How to close the Print preview page with code

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code that runs through and collects some data to print off several sheets. each sheet is printed separately and loops through.

I use some code

```
Applications.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PrintPreviewAndPrint")
```

to open the print preview page then some code in a form to either print with a click of a button or exit. This works ok but when it's finished looping through I am left with the print preview page still open.

Can you help me with the code to close the print preview page and return to the home tab.

```
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PrintPreviewAndPrint")

'opens the form "ContinuePrinting"

ContinuePrinting.Show
Do
    DoEvents
  Loop Until ContinuePrinting.Visible
  'Wait until the form is closed
  Do While ContinuePrinting.Visible
    DoEvents
  Loop

Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("FilePrintQuick")


Sheets("SeqTaskPrint").Activate
Range("as2").Select
        
         Next WP
         
  Application.CommandBars.??????????????????
```

Comment: Thanks , but the print preview page is still there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SendKeys ("{ESC}")`.

**Note**: `SendKeys` are unreliable but can be useful if used properly.

Here is an example. The code will wait for 5 seconds before closing `Print Preview`

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub ShowAndClosePrintPreview()
    Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PrintPreviewAndPrint")

    '~~> Wait for 5 seconds
    Wait 5
    
    '~~> Close print preview
    SendKeys ("{ESC}")
End Sub

Private Sub Wait(ByVal nSec As Long)
    nSec = nSec + Timer
    While nSec > Timer
        DoEvents
    Wend
End Sub
```

**In Action**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help but that still leaves the print preview page showing?

Comment: comment the activate/select statements and try again

Comment: still the same, the preview page is still showing?

Comment: Possible to see your file? The answer that I posted is tried and tested. There is something which is taking the focus away before `Sendkeys` and hence it is not working.

Comment: Your right. I set up a blank sheet and it worked fine. would it have something to do with eth loop in the code?

Comment: Looks like your `ContinuePrinting` form is still open when you call the code?

Comment: thankyou for your excellent help, you were right. I moved the send keys code into the userform control code and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. This is the reason why I put the note `Note: SendKeys are unreliable but can be useful if used properly.` :)

Comment: Thanks, I have been trying for a week (on and off) to sort it out, really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

With a little research, I found the below Code Snippet which should work.

```
ActiveSheet.PrintOut preview:=False
```

Or
ActiveSheet.PrintOut preview:=False

Source: [Chandoo.Org](https://chandoo.org/forum/threads/switching-print-preview-on-and-off-in-vba.5454/)

Comment: Thanks, I tried that. It seems to just print the document again, I am still left with the print preview page showing.